# Regex - Disallow certain characters to appear consecutively

Tags: java, regex

I'm not sure if this is possible or not:

Writing a program to convert an infix notation to postfix notation. All is working well so far but trying to implement validation is proving difficult.

I'm trying to use a regex to validate an infix notation, conforming to the following rules:

1. String must only start with a number or `(` (program does not allow negative numbers)
2. String must only end with number or `)`
3. String must only contain `0-9*/()-+`
4. String must not allow following characters to appear together `+*/-`

I have a regex which conforms to the first 3 rules:

```
(^[0-9(])([0-9+()*]+)([0-9)]+$)
```

Is it possible to use regex to implement the last rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Michał Turczyn that regex is not the task for this, but not with the reason. It is easy to implement your restrictions. However, your restrictions also allow expressions like `(0+3`, `2(*4)`, `((((1`, and other things you likely don't want - so regex validation is kind of pointless. If you were writing this with a regex engine with some significant power like PCRE (Perl, PHP) or Onigmo (Ruby), you can fake a parser in regex; but in Java, regex is quite restricted in what it can do. It is enough for the requirements in the question, though:

```
^[0-9(](?:(?![+*/-][+*/-])[0-9+*/()-])*[0-9)]$
```

- starts with digit or paren
- any number of repetitions of any allowed character, such that that character and the next character aren't both operators
- ends with digit or thesis.

Comment: You're right. Never considered the the other expressions it would still allow. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer only to fourth rule as you have problem only with it.

Yes, there is a possibility, but I think regex is not appropriate tool to check that...

This pattern `^(?(?=.*\+)(?!.*[\*\/-])).+$` will match any string that contain `+` and not contain other characters: `/`,`*`,`-`. For one character is already lengthy and hard to read. [See demo](https://regex101.com/r/PK2XHv/1).

It uses conditional expression `(?...)` to check if lookahead checking for `+` was successfull, if it is, then negative lookahead assures that you won't have any of `\*-` characters.

For all characters, the regex will become very big and hard to maintain.

That's why I don't recommend it for this task.